# Why does my initState() not call a function that uses sharedprefs before the widget is built?

Tags: function, asynchronous, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

In my flutter app I'm trying to create a one time / first time screen that shows a tutorial when the app is first downloaded. I decided to use Shared Preferences to store the data. But whenever I run the app I get **Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null** : Thats due to the variable *_seen* in my code not being initialized and when I looked further I found out that my code is initializing the variable after it is being used to build a widget. Is there anyway to fix this?

My code

```
void main() => runApp(Start());

class Start extends StatefulWidget 
{
  @override
  App createState() => new App();
}

class App extends State<Start>
{
  bool _seen;

  @override
  void initState() 
  {
    print(1);
    _checkFirstTime();
    super.initState();
  }

  _checkFirstTime() async 
  {
    print(1.1);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();  
    _seen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);
    print(1.2);
  }  

  _updateFirstTime() async
  {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();  
    _seen = true;
    prefs.setBool('seen', true);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) 
  {
    print(2);
    bool seen = _seen;  
    if (_seen == false) {_updateFirstTime();}
    print(2.1);
    return MaterialApp( 
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: seen ? HomeScreen() : SignUpScreen(),
    );
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem here is due to the SharedPreferences API being asyncronous, so the build() method is firing before prefs is loaded, as expected.

It's going:

```
1. initState
2. _checkFirstTime (starts)
3. build 
4. _checkFirstTime (completes)
```

There's many ways you can fix it, you could initialize to false, you could use a FutureBuilder, you could use a _isInitComplete flag etc.

A simple fix could be to just add this at the top of your build:

`if(_seen == null) return Container();`

Now, an empty view will be shown for the 4ms or whatever it takes for the Prefs to finish loading. This is functionally the same as using a FutureBuilder. Don't forget to call `setState()` at the end of `_checkFirstTime` to trigger a refresh.

Comment: Just used what you said and it worked. Thanks a lot yo!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1 : You can put logic `checkFirstTime()` in `main()` 
Step 2 : To use `updateFirstTime()` in `build`, you can use `initialRoute` to avoid 
`seen` value update cause `SingupScreen()` suddenly change to `HomeScreen()`

code snippet

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  seen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);

  runApp(MyApp());
}
...
initialRoute: seen == false || seen == null ? "/sign" : "/",
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => HomeScreen(
      title: "demo",
    ),
    "/sign": (context) => SignUpScreen(),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

bool seen;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  seen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: seen == false || seen == null ? "/sign" : "/",
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomeScreen(
          title: "demo",
        ),
        "/sign": (context) => SignUpScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class SignUpScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  _updateFirstTime() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    seen = true;
    prefs.setBool('seen', true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (seen == false) {
      _updateFirstTime();
    }
    return Text('SignUpScreen');
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this just making main an async function?

Comment: not really. there are some extra works, you can see full code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Future builder in this case. Here is an example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Start());

class Start extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  App createState() => new App();
}

class App extends State<Start> {
  bool _seen;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print(1);
    _checkFirstTime();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> _checkFirstTime() async {
    print(1.1);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _seen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);
    print(1.2);
    return _seen;
  }

  _updateFirstTime() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _seen = true;
    prefs.setBool('seen', true);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(2.1);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: _checkFirstTime(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {

          if (_seen == false) {
            _updateFirstTime();
          }

          return snapshot.data ? HomeScreen() : SignUpScreen();
        } else {
          //you can put anything while retrieving data 
          return Container();
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```